# Error in IE10 using velocity.js

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-10, velocity.js

Help!

There seems to be some sort of error in velocity.js in regards to being run in IE 10 and below.

I get this highlighted in the console: "var n=r.toString().match(/blur(([0-9]+[A-z]+))/i)" with "Unable to get property 'toString' of undefined or null reference".

Any ideas why?

Comment: Can you paste what line of code is the error occuring? Just to clarify again, error only occurs on IE right?

Comment: Its because your variable `r` is undefined. Posting code you've written would be helpful

Comment: Yes, errors only in IE. The code is within velocity.js, a widely used plugin for animations.

See the error here: http://www.skyfoxdesign.com/wp

Comment: The error is in file: jquery.velocity.min.js, Line: 3, Column: 15254

Comment: You can start by using the version that's not minified (without the "min").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add an exception that all versions of ie ignore my instances of velocity blur. After that the code ignored the blur and ran perfectly.